# vue.js -- can't change style of svg through css, and in dom it applies element.style instead of class name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

I wanted to change the style of some SVG images. Like usual, i did it with css, but it didn't do anything. I noticed that when i inspect the page, in the style part, the style is under the tag `'element.style'`, and that's probably why i always failed to access.

I also tried to change the style with script, but same issue. When i tried console.log() the value, it showed the value changed to the right one i wanted in the console, but still it didn't get applied in the page and in the style part of the inspect panel, the styles are still under the element.style tag.
[image]

I created the component so as to use in multiple places in the main component.

```
<template>
  <div :class="iconsClassName" :ref="iconsClassName">
    <div :class="iconClassName" v-for="(icon, index) in icons" :key="index">
      <a :href="icon.mediaLink" target="_blank">
        <svg style="width:16px;height:16px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path fill="#ffffff" :d="icon.icon" />
        </svg>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

css part in the main component,and i want to change the style in one of the places where i used the above component.

```
.mediaBottom a svg {
  width: 21px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

I know i can make it work by binding the value with props and give values every time when i used it, but i'm just curious why the above solutions didn't work?

Comment: The inline style `style="width:16px;height:16px"` overrides the css. Why do you have the width and height in the template if you want to add it with css?

Answer (score 1):

Normal css cannot override inline-style. If you want to override inline-style, you need to add !important. For example:

`.mediaBottom a svg {
  width: 21px !important;
  height: 24px !important;
}`

Comment: Thanks @DarknessZX, it worked. Werid because i tried to add the !important before but didn't work, maybe i added to the wrong place. Anyway, thanks.